# Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28'

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I reinstall my windows and android studio . after the installation , I change the sdk folder in android studio settings to the sdk that was before the re installation .

now , I get this error: 
Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28'

I've tried everything , invalidate, restart, remove the platform for android-28 and re download it via sdk manager , removed .gradle folder and every thing I knew

this is the image from my sdk manager :
[image]

[image]

could you help me ? how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: please check if you are behind any network proxy.

Comment: @VikashKumar pretty sure

Answer (score 0):

In the SDK Manager enable the "show package details"
then select the android sdk and build tools to download.
[image]
[image]

Then check the build.gradle content.
[image]